# Variable equals zero and doesn't change in the "paint" part

Tags: java, variables, graphics, paint

I have a problem in this client TCP/IP program,
in the "paint" part, the X and Y variables are always = 0
Why is that? how can i fix it to take the values sent by the Server?

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.net.*;
   import java.applet.*;
   import java.applet.Applet;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;


public class TCPClient extends java.applet.Applet {
public static int X;
public static int Y;

public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
{

 //while (true){

 InetAddress IPHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
 Socket ClientSocket = new Socket(IPHost, 6789);
 DataOutputStream outToSurver = new DataOutputStream(ClientSocket.getOutputStream());
 InputStreamReader innSocket = new InputStreamReader (ClientSocket.getInputStream());
 BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(innSocket);
 TCPClient.X = Integer.parseInt(inFromServer.readLine());
 TCPClient.Y = Integer.parseInt(inFromServer.readLine());
 Point Location = new Point(X,Y);
 System.out.println("The location is at :" + Location);

 ClientSocket.close();

  //}

  }

   public void paint( Graphics g )
    {
        g.drawString( "My Map", TCPClient.X, TCPClient.Y);
        System.out.println("X="+TCPClient.X+"Y="+TCPClient.Y);

    }
   }
```

Comment: What about your server, he sent this values X and Y?

Comment: Yes, and the output of:
      System.out.println("The location is at :" + Location);
is correct as the server sent.

Comment: what does the system.out.println say? Is this really a problem for g.drawString? Or is the problem before?

Comment: @user2175304 How `System.out.println("The location is at :" + Location);` can be correct if you wrote that X and Y always 0?

Comment: The problem is in the "paint" method when i paint the location of "My Map" and the printed output of the "paint(Graphics g) "

Comment: @user2175304 Maybe `main` method invoke after `paint` method.